# Not really a bad answer

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I almost flagged [this answer in a First Posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18206986) as NAA when I saw the first paragraph:

> Actually the type Array.Index is an alias to the type Int so you can do the same operation as if you had an integer with the result of the method index(of:).

To me, it looks like a valid answer, but not worth an upvote, so I clicked "No Action Needed". It then turned out it's an audit.

Had I given it only a glance before casually giving a flag, I would've passed this audit. This has never been what review audits are intended for. I ended up giving my own judge and let it go after a while of thinking.

I've passed at least 20 audits prior to this, in the past week, without failing a single one (except this), and banning for 8 days is a bit too harsh. I'm surely not a robo reviewer and I've been reviewing carefully.

For those who think this is a link-only answer, please consider this example:

> **Q**: Why do apples fall down instead of up?
>   **A**: Because the Earth has gravity. You can see Isaac Newton's discovery [here](link).

It *is* a complete answer even with the link removed, isn't it?

Thanks to *Josh Caswell* for providing [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzEnz.png) of [the timeline of that post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47664456/timeline).

Comment: Not-so-careful reviewers are ruining the review system. I'll stay away from FP and LA and stick to Suggested Edits (where being careful can do all the good job).

Comment: Yeah this is obviously the work of poor reviewers. I'm really inclined on putting all the blame on them and none on the audit system.

Comment: What is it that you want to know about the timeline?

Comment: @BoltClock Come on. That's a controversial post. I hope you can lift my ban and invalidate that post from being used as further review audits. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Or simply all audits that used that very post, not exacltly the timeline.

Comment: How about a screenshot? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzEnz.png

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm the only one audited with that post and failed??? Anyway thank you.

Comment: That's what it says. /me shrugs

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the max of 7 days from - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days for how the automated review bans work in terms of duration.

Comment: @iBug I too got banned today for 8 days even after I passed 3-4 tests and failed only a single audit. I was also tricked by some Late answers which seemed correct and I got banned. This is sad. They should include the ratio to the number of audits passed vs number of audits failed.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Passing only 3~4 is really a small number, however.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I have a habit, that I click the link to the answer and raise an extra VLQ flag or cast a downvote before recommending deletion in LQP review. This has helped me identify audits, despite being in only a small portion (I would have made the right review even without this action in 90%+ cases).

Comment: @IBug But I passed all those 3-4 audits in around 60 minutes.

Comment: @iBug me too I do the same as you said but sometimes. I am only a  Moderator. But I don't do that when I encounter a legit answer to the question.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal An average man with the basic consciousness could also have done so. Just like you won't be praised if you got 60 in an exam because you're expected to do *much* better, say 80 or 90. 1/4 to 1/3 is a considerably high failure rate, in fact.

Comment: @iBug I agree you chose the right action here so I've lifted the ban - however, you got 8 days here because you got a 4 day ban (within the last 30 days) for failing a suggested edit audit that was just so obviously an audit and deliberate vandalism of a post. Tread carefully please - if you fail another audit (as long as it was a fair one) within 30 days you'll be on a 16 day review ban.

Comment: @JonClements Thank you very much. Can you also please invalidate the very post from being used as further audits, possibly by undeleting it and clear the two comments from previous LQP reviewers?

Comment: Possibly - but I'd have to think about it - undeleting it may subject it to downvotes if people are as like minded as those who chose to delete it to start with vs its chances of being used as an audit again. (Bear in mind current added exposure to that post via this meta one)

Comment: @iBug I think you are right but in my case, since the time I became a Reviewer I have passed too many audits and failed only 4-5 audits.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Don't be too self-confident. Review audits are usually *very* obvious. Failing 4-5 of them is, at least to me, a bad record.

Comment: @iBug you realise you've failed 3 resulting in bans which means you've probably failed ~10 right?

Comment: @JonClements Although it's a bad practice, I'm thinking of voting it up. In addition to preventing it from being used as audits, an upvote is also an appropriate reward for being addressed to in the actually accepted answer with a nice score.

Comment: @JonClements Sir, please check my record one time. I am improving the quality of my reviews after I got banned for the first time.

Comment: @JonClements I'm not quite sure how you understood my words, but what I intended to mean is that 4-5 failures sounds too many to me (failing many = bad record, right?). Assume my memory is right, this is the 5th I've failed.

Comment: @iBug seems sensible - I've undeleted it. Please note I was in two minds about lifting the ban as if it wasn't that audit I'm not entirely convinced it wouldn't have been another. However, it was an unfair audit and I tend to give the benefit of doubt where possible. Just move forward judiciously please.

Comment: @iBug I have not failed many for a bad record. I remembered correctly I failed only 4-5 times.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I admit the current threshold is a bit too low. Given that this is my 5th and a controversial one, I've failed 4 fair ones. I'm raising it up here because I believe it's a wrong one. You can also ask for justice if you think your last one was wrong.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal this is iBug's post about a bad audit. If you want to raise your own meta post then feel free. However, it won't do you much good. I can't see a bad audit in the ones you've had and you've straight run into new bans straight after being unbanned - that's a sign you're not taking enough time to review correctly or are mistaken in how you should review items. I'd recommend reading up on the how to review guides before your ban expires and once able to review again - do so carefully.

Comment: @iBug yeah you are right about threshold. I think it is a bit low. Well no problem lets move forward with it :)

Comment: @JonClements Sir, thank you for your time and paying attention to my problem. I think I should go through review guides one more time and should stop reviewing more frequently because I am a fast reader I read up stuffs or posts quickly and gives reviews quickly. I think this is wrong. I should do improve my reviewing quality more after this ban. Once again heartily thank you for guiding me in this case Sir. :)

Comment: @JonClements Sir... Your comment is misleading people into thinking I've failed 10 audits. That's not true. I wish you would fix it.

Comment: @iBug What about it isn't true?  Given how many times you've been banned, you'd need to have failed *at least* that many audits to get banned that many times.

Comment: @Servy You should have known that **one failure** in 30 days since last ban expired instates a new ban.

Comment: @iBug That is quite more disconcerting, actually. You mean that, three times, you failed an audit, then failed another one in the 30 days period that followed it? Please stahp.

Comment: @Servy to be fair to iDebug it's a kind of best guess number. The mod tools for some of this stuff is limited to certain time periods and a bit fiddly to work things out from... I'm just going from what I could immediately access, allowing a bit of give and take that you're allowed with audits, and have generally found that if you've ended up banned for 8 days, you're most likely to be around the ~10 having failed audits even if they haven't ended up in an automated ban. By no means is it a concrete statement - it's more a "from my experience that means that..."

Comment: @JonClements You can check my rep history and see a rapid gain from 1.7k to 4.1k in November. It was after I got 3k that I really started  reviewing.

Comment: Reputation means little when it comes to reviewing - just means you have access to more queues, some open up at 500, the last one at 5000... not sure what point you're making.

Comment: @JonClements I had hardly ever reviewed any when I was below 3k (because my primary target was CV and Reopen).

Comment: Sure. Anyway - your concern seems to be about my statement of ~10 failed audits. I've clarified that's not a concrete number, but from my experience it's not an unrealistic ball park number (based on information I could conveniently access and knowledge of how this all works)... That's what I was clarifying on this post - that's all.

Comment: @JonClements That's all. Conclude. I want to keep away from the comment section of this post. It's all messed up.

Comment: Masters in pointless argumentation, achieved :)

Comment: @DukeDidntNukeEm What are you dissatisfied with?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I agree. The answer looks like a valid answer to me, not a very good one, but still an answer, and not really bad one. Its wording is a bit crude, some clarification and expansion would be welcome, but I do not see anything warranting deletion. Given it is earlier answer than the accepted one, and even the accepted one references it by saying

> which is a typealias for Int, as Nonuld say

I think it should not be deleted.

Comment: You should cite the full text: "The problem isn't that it's of type Array.index, which is a typealias for Int, as Nonuld says." The problem was something completely different than what was written in the answer. I agree that giving the wrong answer still doesn't mean it should have been deleted.

Comment: Wrong answers are not bad by definition, knowing how to *not* to solve a problem has value as well.  As long as it is nicely voted down so everybody can tell.  But this is an *evil* wrong answer, the kind that states an obvious but irrelevant truth and a link that costs the reader an hour with no hope.  Like this one.  The OP made the classic problem of ignoring good advice from people that know the tag well, and himself knowing nothing about it.  That it "looked good" was exactly the problem with the post.  And it didn't, it wasn't even around anymore.  He didn't look.

Comment: "as Nonuld says" isn't a strong reference; it's perfectly fine to edit that bit out if there's no other good reason to keep the answer.

Comment: Could perhaps someone comment on that answer? I admit even after reading the comment here by @HansPassant I do not understand what is so wrong and evil with it. How is stating "type Array.index is a typealias for Int" irrelevant? The OP asked how to get `Int`, not `Array.index `. This tells him by getting `Array.index ` he already got hit `Int`. Is there something wrong with this notion? How can the link cost an hour? The link is to page which contains just a few sentences, just confirming `Array.index` is the typealias.

Comment: @Suma Because the problem boils down to converting an optional integer into a concrete integer. This answer implies that no conversion is required, because `Array.Index` is *already* an `int`. But that's not the actual problem here; the problem is converting an *optional* `Array.Index` into an `int`. Saying they're the same thing and shouldn't need any conversion is confusing because it's an answer to a question no one asked, and because it implies that the error shouldn't happen; and is potentially caused by something else.

Comment: Well, technically it is in answer to a question somebody has asked (the question formulated the problem as getting `Int` instead of `Array.Index`), but you are correct and I understand it now. The fact the original question made an assumption which is not true does not make the answer correct. I hope the comment I have made on the answer as a result of this discussion makes it clear enough.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a black or white case. The answer is mostly a "link-only answer" which is discouraged and reason enough to delete it. What made it tricky is that the answerer included the link as part of the explanation. Note that link-only answers often *do* answer the question - they are an attempt to answer it, but should be deleted anyway.

Had he written like this instead, I doubt the answer would have been deleted:

> Actually the type Array.Index is a typealias to the type Int, so you can do the same operation as if you had an integer with the result of the method index(of:).
>   More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/index).

I wouldn't really blame the VLQ reviewers for this, it is not an easy review. Nor do I think the OP did anything wrong by saying that the post is ok.

What's to blame is the horribly broken audit system. This is a very badly picked audit. Like always.

Comment: I agree in this case the audit was badly picked. I disagree this is "like always". Most audits I have encountered were fine. Perhaps this depends on the tags you are reviewing? (I am mostly revieving `scala` and `c++`).

Comment: @Suma This has nothing to do with tags or technical content at all, it is all about general moderation policies. Just browse meta for failed review audits and you'll see that broken audits is a major problem, and has been so for many years.

Comment: The main issue is that the only signal the system had was a downvote and the initial reviewers thought it warranted deletion - ergo - "looks okay" - is not a proper response. However - depending how you read the answer - it does look okay - so reviewers with slightly different standards are tripping over each other here...

Comment: @JonClements Which is the root of the problem. The system does not have enough information to form a good audit. But does so anyway.

Comment: At first glance, this seems like a link-only answer. But in fact, the part that I quoted **is** a complete answer, even if the links are removed.

Comment: The audit system is flawed, but in this case I can forgive it - the *entire* actions reviewers took on that post told it "this should be deleted"... When looked at more throughly, you can see that deletion isn't really required, although some re-wording/other improvement really wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Consider this question: Q: *Why does apples fall down instead of up?* A: Because the Earth has gravity. You can see Isaac Newton's discovery \[here](link).