# Why did I fail this audit for LQP?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed an LQP review audit for an answer to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369914/how-do-i-capture-a-raw-soap-request-for-wcf-web-service/47836738#47836738)

The answer was as follows:

> If want to see raw SOAP body you probably need a custom
>   [MessageEncoder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder?view=netframework-4.7.1). And unlike message inspectors
>   (IDispatchMessageInspector / IClientMessageInspector) it captures any
>   malformed XML data.
>
> In order to implement tracing using this approach you need to wrap a
>   standard [textMessageEncoding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding) as custom [binding element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and apply that
>   custom binding to endpoint in your [config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-binding-transport-and-encoding).
>
> This approach is demonstrated in WcfSoapLogger:
>   https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger

I received the message

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise,
>   spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will
>   find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

It looked proper to me, but I'm still new to the LQP review queue.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Looks like spam to me.  You should have identified it as such in the queue, or at least considered it as a possibility enough to look into it and find out that it was already deleted for being spam, which would tell you that it's an audit.

Comment: It looks like it was probably deleted as spam, the same user had another very similar answer deleted 4 days earlier.

Comment: @Servy I must be missing something very obvious. To me it appear it's explaining how to use the MessageEncoder Class to solve the problem in the question. What am I missing?

Comment: IMO that's not really spammy.  The question is a bit of a resource request, so that probably led to these kinds of answers.

Comment: @ryanyuyu is it marked as spam because of the link to WcfSoapLogger? I saw that link as a demonstration of how to use MessageEncoder to solve the problem, not a spammy promotion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That post, along with 14 others by the same person, was flagged as spam and deleted. Each of the answers promoted their GitHub repository, without disclosure that it was theirs.

It's not the most obvious or egregious case of spam, but the people who flagged it were correct in that it was excessive self-promotion. My deletion of the posts validated the spam flag and caused it to be used as an audit.

It's not a good audit without the context of the other posts, but I'm worried about upsetting the flagger if I now go through and invalidate their flags. It would be real nice if [I could remove this audit case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/135615) without that, but I currently can't.

If people think this is enough of a problem, I can go through these and invalidate the spam flags on the answers.

Comment: Isnt this why we're supposed to use a custom flag for excessive self promotion?

Comment: @TinyGiant - I prefer those in cases like this more so that I'm made aware that they have a history of self-promotion. The person flagging this as spam isn't wrong, but it does cause an inconvenient situation with audits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Not a huge issue. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. I'll try to look at user history when I see a linked repo.

Comment: I for one believe it's a reasonably good audit because it catches reviewers who [miss very important check of proper affiliation disclosure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361512/839601)

Comment: @gnat perhaps, but the audit should tell the reviewer this so they can learn how to catch this issue, instead of telling the reviewer that the post was "abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable". Failing this audit didn't make me more likely to check proper affiliation in the future until I asked about the audit on meta.

Comment: @Goose well now you know that prior to clicking Looks OK (at the post with links and without disclosure) reviewer is expected to go to poster's profile and check for affiliation, don't you? (FWIW if memory serves I was one of those who flagged this "capslocky" guy and I found the issue with their posts exactly the way I describe, by comparing stuff in their profile against links advertised in their posts)

Comment: It seems like picking random answers as audit candidates is counter productive. Rather than changing behavior and improving moderation results, it may just lead to merely supporting the status quo. Seems to be the definition of "echo chamber". In this case, there is nothing to indicate a LQP without additional context. Not every flagged answer should be considered for use as an audit.

Comment: @picciano I believe it is correct to expect reviewer to check additional context if they choose "Looks OK" because it's the only way to catch plagiarism and inappropriate self-promotion (choosing Recommend Deletion is a whole different game, it indeed shouldn't require such checks). Even if audits were picked or verified manually I would keep that one