# Possible bad audit on LQP Queue

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I just came across this [audit in LQP Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19122558):

> [image]

It looks like a bad audit for LQP, because,

1. It *does* seem to answer the question. The question is about difference between `include` and `require` functions, and the answer does contain some information about it.
2. Although there is a link at the bottom, it is **not** a link only answer.
3. The answer is not properly formatted. Someone might be easily tempted to choose "Edit" in order to fix the formatting.

In fact, the post is a spam as the link at the bottom leads to an article that is written by the same person. But that isn't obvious from the answer itself or the URL of the link. So someone would have to click on the link and see the author's name on the article to realize that it is spam.

Here's the article the question leads to:

[image]

I noticed a [similar audit from January](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361772/5894241) where another answer was used as an audit based on spam flags. So my questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable audit question?
2. Is it expected from a reviewer in LQP queue to watch out for spam (or undisclosed self promotion) as well?

---

<sup>**Note**: I did not fail the audit. This is not a rant disguised as a question.</sup>

Comment: When using the review queues you should most certainly have your eyes peeled for spam, as it's one of your most important jobs as a reviewer to notice it.  When you see an extremely low quality post with a a link to somewhere, you should, at a minimum, have red flags be popping up and looking pretty closely at it, because it's a very common tactic for spammers to surround their spam links with something resembling an answer at a glance.  A closer inspection of the post would, at a minimum, lead you to finding out that it was deleted as spam.

Comment: @Servy That's a bit surprising to me. In particular for this particular instance I wasn't sure of the correct choice even after identifying that it was self-promotion/spam. Particularly because (A) LQP queue gets posts from NAA flags, and I thought NAA flag on a Spam post would be incorrect (so it can be declined). (B) Even if this were a link only answer, the option reads `This is a link-only answer (and not spam)` which again gives the impression that LQP queue is not meant to handle spam.

Comment: [1/2] (1) I'm not so sure about whether that answer qualifies as spam: the link is relevant to the Q&A, and the essential parts of it (according to the OP's judgement) are included in the actual answer. If I wrote an answer that summarises a blog post of mine which would be too long for Stack Overflow's format and include a link to said blog post at the end of it, I would be really surprised to see it flagged it as spam.

Comment: [2/2] (2) That said, the answer is certainly low quality, to the extent it is a lazy, poorly formatted copy-paste of excerpts of the blog post. I won't pretend I actually understand how LQP is supposed to work, so I won't make claims about how it should have been handled in the queue.

Comment: @duplode: If you link to your own blog, you have to explicitly stated that this is your blog. Everything else is [unwanted self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @duplode If you check the linked post, Brad explains that in that instance the answer was picked for audit as it was one of 14 answers that were considered spammy. It might be a similar case for this one as well.

Comment: @Nisarg You're right that it's not NAA, and choosing the option you quoted isn't appropriate (as it explicitly says).  For a case like this the appropriate action would be a custom mod flag, although as it's already been deleted you'd have seen that it was an audit before actually getting to that point, as you'd see it was already deleted.

Comment: @BDL Good point. Taking that into account, if I ran into such an answer outside of the queue, I might be inclined to not assume malice and edit the attribution in and/or leave a comment to the OP about the issue. In this specific situation, though, the answer is very late and doesn't seem to add anything to the preexisting answers, which doesn't help its case at all.

Comment: @duplode: Yes, I agree. I don't think it's a good audit and I would have most probably also tried to edit it.

Comment: Just throwing this out there: Lets look at the unwanted self-promotion guildlines: *`Don't talk about your [x] too much."`* Check. There's an answer here, followed by "see also this blog." *`Don't tell - show!`* It's an explanation. Check. *`Don't include links except to support what you've written.`* Removing the link leaves a valid answer. Check. Does the post forget to say "my blog?" Yes, it does. But that can be fixed with an edit. The **only** reason this is spam is because of user behavior that cannot be seen from within the review queue.