# Why is this considered spam or offensive?

Tags: support, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I failed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18558689) but I don't see why.

> *...It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive
>   rather than helpful.*

How exactly is the post *'abusive nonsense'*, *'otherwise irredeemable'*? or does it land on something else?

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18558689]

Comment: @Kendra It's a crappy "fix my code for me" question where someone dumps some code and someone posted an answer.  You've seen hundreds so far today alone.

Comment: My guess is that there is some form of voting fraud going on here.  The same person (or group of people) probably posted the question with the expressed purpose of posting this answer and upvoting each other.  At least that's what this smells like to me.

Comment: @Servy Sure it does smell that way. But how is the _answer_ a spam? I'm not necessarily sure of the fraud or anything.

Comment: If it's posted for the expressed purpose of committing voting fraud, then that would be abusive; I wouldn't be surprised if someone flagged it for that reason.  I doubt it was flagged for spam.

Comment: ... and voting fraud _offends me_ :)

Comment: Yes, but I don't necessarily have the judgment for that, do I? The idea that this is a potential fraud offends is a reason for recommending deletion?

Comment: @Servy That's not really an appropriate use of either of those flags. -- We're looking into this more. There's a bunch of posts affected and they're really screwing up the review audit system.

Comment: it's just a bad audit, nothing more.

Comment: @Nae Voting fraud alone isn't reason for deleting.  Creating garbage posts just for the purpose of committing voting fraud is most certainly grounds for deletion.

Comment: @animuson I'm not saying that's what they should have done (the appropriate solution is a custom flag), I'm just saying I expect that's what someone actually did.

Comment: @Servy How is it a garbage though? It claims to fix the problem(s) OP claims to have.

Comment: @Nae The OP is themselves.  They created multiple accounts, used one to post some random code dump of some code with a simple syntax error, and then used another account to say that there was a syntax error in their code, and then they upvote all of the posts with all of the accounts.  You could do that with a quality question and a good answer, and it'd be just voting fraud.  They did it with a crap question of no value (as is pretty typical of the type of person that feels the need to commit voting fraud).

Comment: Do those comments on the answer appear in the actual audit?  I can't remember.

Comment: @Servy Well, I don't exactly see it that way tbh. All I'm seeing is a typo question getting answered by whomever. I do understand how the question may need to be deleted but not the answer separately as well. Not without a given _fact_ that this whole thing being fraud, not even then perhaps.

Comment: @ryanyuyu They did when it informed me of my audit failure, didn't take ss then though.

Comment: @Nae And that's why you failed the audit.

Comment: The answer itself, ignoring the fact that the user who posted it was cheating the system, was fine (though not useful imo). but the user who posted it *was* cheating the system, which is why it was flagged the way it was, and why it was eligible to be an audit. You couldn't have possibly known that. You did nothing wrong. This is simply a bad audit. If anything it was just flagged incorrectly.

Comment: @KevinB exactly. If reviewers are expected to recognize the deleted remnants of a voting ring, they need to be given the tools or knowledge to detect them. Too many audits turn out to be "read the moderator's mind and do whatever he did", but mods have many more resources to make the right decison than users have.

Comment: It's almost as if a checkbox on the flag/deletion dialog for moderators along the lines of "Conclusion required additional research / contextual information." which would in-turn prevent any such marked posts from being used as audits.

Comment: @TinyGiant - The easier solution is to destroy the accounts at the source level and mark the accounts as being spammers / trolls, rather than using flags. That would have achieved the same result here without the bad audits, and we have the tools to do this currently. The moderator involved was trying to stop an ongoing problem, but accidentally caused a secondary one via the use of flags instead of account deletion.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, after reading the accusatory comments under it, I actually thought, "well if the user is fraudulent, then it's the mod's place to take it down or whatnot. I can't simply recommend it for deletion based on 'he said... she said'.".

Comment: In any case, animuson's answer at the above-linked duplicate explains what happened here. This sounds like a weird case of a bunch of puppets who might have been exploiting Developer Stories to prevent their accounts from being deleted (even by moderators), so I think moderator spam flags were used in a desperate attempt to block IPs and get them to stop. These questions and answers are not appropriate audits, and were tripping up a bunch of people. Hopefully they've all been cleared up.

Comment: @Nae you could fail audit only if you picked Looks OK (which you apparently did, didn't you). How in the world could you pick Looks OK after seeing these comments? Or maybe you are proficient in technical matters of the question and answer to see what I can't see and be sure that it's really an OK content? and if this not the case I wonder if you know that **[There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)**

Comment: @KevinB laziness of reviewers clicking Looks OK sometimes scares me. [They don't check for plagiarism, they don't check for inappropriate self-promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361512/839601), they don't try to judge question and answer on technical grounds. They just skim over a sequence of letters and digits that doesn't feel suspicious at a first glance and stamp it OK

Comment: @gnat I'm not certain but, I would pick "Looks OK" even with all the information in this post here. I do remember thinking "well, even if this _answer_ is what the comments under it claim it to be, it's not a VLQ. If it's fraudulent, then ban the users, and remove the questions." Which points no directons but "Looks OK" for the _answer_ imo.

Comment: then it probably was a good thing that you failed the audit and I wish that there were more audits like that

Comment: @gnat I agree with Nae's assessment and would have chosen the same action. Such a post should not be deleted through review. The problematic question and accounts should be dealt with. The _question_ could be dealt with by the community but the accounts should be left to the mods to handle.

Comment: @gnat - This was a bad audit, plain and simple. Nae was not at fault here. This was caused by a bizarre set of circumstances that hopefully have been corrected now.

Comment: @TinyGiant you seem to put words in my mouth, why, does this strawman makes it easier to argue. I do not say that this post should be deleted via review

Comment: @BradLarson if ignoring comments pointing to serious issue is not a fault then you can just shut down review and handle LQ flags yourself, along with 20 other diamond mods. Oh wait, review was introduced (and even further simplified by lowering deletion votes from 6 to 4) only because it turned out that moderators are unable to handle floods of garbage damaging the site. In case you forgot - unlike diamonds LQ reviewers have 20 items per day (not 200, not 2000) - plenty time to do simple checks like that

Comment: @gnat If you are reasonably certain that a post should not be deleted in the LQPRQ, Looks OK _is_ the correct action. Skipping is appropriate when you are _not_ reasonably certain of the correct outcome for a review, not for when a post shouldn't be in the LQPRQ in the first place.

Comment: @gnat I'm not _ignoring_ comments, I judge that I don't just have to step in.

Comment: @Nae it's simple really. Either the answer is OK and then comments are abusive and should be flagged for mod attention. Or comments are OK and then there's something wrong with the answer. Third option is to Skip this review and do nothing, it is also legitimate. You picked that post is OK but didn't flag comments, this makes it a poor review no matter how you twist it

Comment: @TinyGiant ^^^ see above. In the case of this audit if reviewer picked Looks OK they should at the very least flag comments

Comment: @gnat _"Either the answer is OK and then comments are abusive and should be flagged for mod attention."_ It's not one of either for me. I believe both the comments _and_ the answer were OK, for the VLQ. While I do agree I should take additional action, which I would probably _custom_ flag the question or at worst the answer.But it was an audit, I was made aware of the fact that it was a closed answer anyway, so I simply didn't think it as far as that. But again even if I did, I'd probably custom flag the question, or both if there were additional answers from unsuspected answerers.

Answer (score 7):

Since audits are chosen via an automated process, you'll get some bad ones every now and then.  **This is a poor choice for an audit, and you shouldn't be penalized for failing this one.**  The answer is a reasonable attempt to answer the question and non-spammy when considered alone, which it all that you should consider when in the VLQ reviews.

Even if there was indeed voting fraud or repetitions of posts, it is not your responsibility to hunt this down.  In fact, the only way to know about the user's sketchy behavior is to actually visit their profile and manually go through all their posts, which can fringe on user stalking/serial voting.  This is exactly the kind of thing moderators are elected to deal with.

That being said, **if you had gone the extra mile, you might not have failed this (poorly chosen) audit**.  Reading the answer and its comments, it becomes apparent that this is a decent answer to an off-topic typo question.  So if you had clicked the link to the question in an attempt to flag/close the question, you would have realized immediately that both the question and answer were deleted.  This would have made the audit obvious.

Comment: Ultimately you can't _know_ even if you do go through each users profiles and perform all sorts of data analysis, cross-referencing, and such _because you ultimately do not know who voted on what_. The only way to _know_ if someone has voted fraudulently is to have diamond level privileges, and even then the amount of information that moderators have access to is very restricted with regards to voting. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @TinyGiant yeah, that's basically what I was trying to communicate.  Going through user profiles with the intention of flagging things is the wrong way to handle these kinds of problems.  Best leave that up to the mods.

Comment: I actually wasn't penalized. But still made me wonder why.

Answer (score -2):

Typically, there's an automated process that selects posts for reviews based on some set of metrics.  Probably has to do with it's score, the fact that it's been deleted by the community users, or some other thing that has to do with it being poorly received.

The automated system isn't perfect.  It can't really evaluate the post and determine whether or not it's really worthy of an audit in it's own right.  Most of what it goes on is how the community treated the post in the first place, and sometimes that results in poor audits.

The reason It was poorly received the first time likely has to do with the fact that it's an ugly block of text, and that a casual reader might assume that it's commenting on some non-crucial element of the question, and not actually an answer.

Comment: This post was used as a review audit because it was deleted with either a rude/abusive or spam flag active against it. The question here is: how exactly is this rude/abusive or spam, and how is one supposed to know this when reviewing.

Comment: Re: your edits since my last comment: The answer in question was spam deleted by a moderator (i.e. a moderator cast a spam flag on it which instantly deleted the answer and marked it as spam), this was not the work of the "community". Moderators should be well aware by now that spam deleting posts like this makes them likely candidates for review audits. Moderators should only be spam deleting posts if the posts themselves are very clearly spam, not because it was loosely involved in, or related to, an instance of spam.

Comment: @TinyGiant nitpick;  the point still stands, that flawed audit questions exist because they are generated from actual data, and actual data does not always make for a good audit question.

Comment: Well, this is a specific problem that has been identified, can be fixed, and warrants discussion. In my opinion a general case answer with some handwaving about how no system is perfect is not useful. We know the cause of bad audits like this, and they can be prevented.

Comment: @TinyGiant  Of course it's useful.  It explains to the OP why, in the general sense, such an answer could be an audit the review queue.  Now the OP knows.

Comment: The OP already knew that (I'm fairly certain), and they were not asking about _how_ such posts come to be audits, but rather how _this_ specific post is _rude/abusive or spam_. In turn disputing the audit (as is the current audit dispute resolution process) and bringing attention to a problem that has been increasingly common in the recent past.

Comment: I actually didn't think the system at all, so this is a bit useful to me. But not exactly why I asked what I asked though. The answer explains _how_ but not exactly _why_.