# How is this question spam or R/A?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, spam

When doing Triage review, I came across this item: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18832925

As a regular action when I found nothing wrong, I went to [the actual post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457935) to check for potentially missed points. It says "This is spam and is therefore hidden". So easy peasy, I passed the audit.

Then I went through everything, including the revision history, but I couldn't understand why it's spam. I checked the words and the only image. Nothing suspicious. The only thing I agree with is that the question is VLQ and thus should be closed.

So please kindly tell a super confused iBug: How on earth is it spam or rude???

---

For less than 10k, here's the post:

> Cannot access website to login on Alibaba Cloud ECS
>
> ```
> I have setup Plesk to ECS but when login IP:8443 is not access? 
>
>
> IP is ok 
> ![enter image description here][1]
>
>
>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAgLt.png
> I installed everything as on another VPS ... And it does not run as I would like.
> ```

Comment: It doesn't seem to show up on metasmoke either.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes. I searched MS and no result for that.

Comment: related: [How is this a bad answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361512/839601) "check you missed... is for illegitimate self-promotion. To check this you'd need to go to poster's profile and verify that links referred in the post aren't affiliated and that other posts from this account do not advertise these links in a suspicious manner..."

Comment: @gnat How do I check for **a deleted user**?? Of course I've learned from that post. A fall into the pit, a gain in my wit.

Comment: @iBug right, a reviewer paying attention (if they intend to pick OK / editing) is expected to notice that user is deleted and do deeper check and drill deeper - which would reveal the audit and pass it

Comment: @Cerbrus looks like metasmoke needs to be informed about Alibaba :)

Comment: I received [a very similar audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18850894) just now. Had I not read this meta post, I wouldn't have known that these are in fact unsalvageable; it looked like a very good post to me.

Comment: For the record, the question you saw was **plagiarized and translated** from [here](https://q.cnblogs.com/q/93181). (Note: Source language is Simplified Chinese)

Comment: @gnat Forgot to mention: Alibaba is a well-known Chinese company, and there's no "self-promotion" to check in these posts. Links to random websites? UGC sites (like GitHub or Blogspot)? No. All no. So "promotion" is an invalid check against these questions as they are only spam **seeds**.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue

Comment: @Will Glad to inform you that Smokey caught its [first Alibaba post](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/107030).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's a spam seed.

There have been a number of accounts asking questions like this and then other accounts answering them with spam for Alibaba.

There's been no indication of affiliation with the product included in the answers and every indication that the same small number of people are running multiple accounts to ask and answer these questions.

We have reached the stage where we destroy the accounts asking these question on sight.

Comment: That's beyond a normal reviewer's knowledge or access...

Comment: @iBug And yet you were able to identify it just fine...so clearly it's *not* beyond a normal reviewers ability to review.

Comment: @iBug That is true, but the earlier questions & answers were obviously spam (like the LongPath spam for those with longer memories) and were flagged as such. Once we became aware of the spam we could deal with it preemptively.

Comment: @Servy I randomly go to the real post even when I found nothing wrong, just for audit check.

Comment: @iBug I also feel obligated to point out that even if you didn't realize it was spam, it's still a bad question, so it's not like you'd fail the audit if you failed to figure out that it was spam on your own.

Comment: @Servy Yes. I said it in the question: I agree is VLQ and if I didn't identify it's spam, I would have CVed it and still passing the audit.

Comment: Asking a real question is too much work for a spammer.  They just copy-paste a question from a crappy forum site.  Plagiarism is another thing to look for.  Original [is here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/forum/read-1512).

Comment: @Servy: _"And yet you were able to identify it just fine...so clearly it's not beyond a normal reviewers ability to review"_ No. They were able to identify the current status of the post. That is very, very different from actually identifying it as spam. This meta question is proof that said identification certainly didn't happen. The audit is bad.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They specifically said that as soon as they read the post, "I felt somewhat uneasy" and were suspicious of it being problematic.  They then chose to investigate further, and found that it was deleted as being spam.  And, as I've already mentioned before, even if they *didn't* realize it was spam, the post is still an awful post most certainly not something that should be passed as a good post, so the only way to fail that audit is to deservedly take the wrong action.  It's a fine audit.  Only a bad reviewer would fail it, which is the mark of a good audit.

Comment: @Servy: "Found that it was deleted as being spam" != "Found that it was spam" which is the point here. They investigated further and _couldn't determine that_. The audit is bad.

Comment: Having to do that much research to pass the review audit is very hard work.  Did anyone ever wonder why the review queues aren't all that popular?

Comment: Agreeing with @LightnessRacesinOrbit, while it's obligated for a reviewer to figure out that *some* of them are of low quality, it's really hard to identify they're spam. [This comment](/posts/comments/558552) from someone else is a good example.

Comment: @Servy Check out [this comment](/posts/comments/558552) from another reviewer for a good example.

Comment: Since it's a higher-level forces playing here, I would consider special status like: "banished from the realm by a site-local god" instead of just 'deleted' and filtering them out from audits. Or some less fantasy term. I can't think of one right now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But they *didn't* need to determine that it was spam.  They needed to determine *that it wasn't okay*.  That they were also able to determine that the post was deleted as being spam *in addition* doesn't automatically make it a bad audit.  If this wasn't spam, and wasn't deleted as spam *the post still isn't okay*, and the reader knew that, and so would have correctly indicated as much.  That makes it a perfectly fine audit.  That it *also* helps people realize that posts like this are spam, and not *just* bad posts, makes it all the *better* as an audit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Your argument would only apply if doing anything other than casting a spam flag would fail the audit, but that's just not the case.

Comment: @Servy For this specific review audit, it's fine. There are other seemingly fine Alibaba spams, which are *much* harder or nearly impossible for reviewers to figure out. My question isn't "this audit is hard", but "**why** is this spam".

Comment: @iBug Sure, you're not saying that this post is a bad audit.  Lightness is, because apparently Lightness thinks that that is a good post for some reason (or that you would fail the audit by doing anything other than a spam flag) which is just *not true*.  But apparently having audits that actually do a good job of making sure people are reviewing correctly is a problem.  Such a shame.

Comment: @Servy This one is a very easy one among all those Alibaba Cloud spams. Other spams are considerably harder to notice. For example, the post used in my audit has 55% (11/20) failure rate, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48655456/timeline) received no "Unsalvageable" during its Triage review, and a 75% (6/8) failure rate when used as audit.

Comment: @iBug Notice how I didn't say that there are no audits that are too difficult to review properly, just that *this isn't one of them*.  That people are failing this *very clearly bad post* doesn't mean the audit is bad, it means it's doing a *good* job of actually catching bad reviewers who aren't doing their job well.  The problem here is that 11 people looked at that post and said it was perfectly fine, even though it's very clearly not.

Comment: @Servy What about the other (this might be a different topic, however)?

Comment: @iBug That's certainly a much more difficult post to properly recognize as problematic.

Comment: Just FYI: From when Charcoal put Alibaba Cloud on it's blacklist, the posts which it's detected have been spam 46.7% of the time. While SmokeDetector will continue to watch for Alibaba Cloud, it's only going to be something that's brought to people's attention (watchlist), rather than something that carries a much heavier indication of spam (blacklist). You can get more detail [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44542019#44542019).