# When should I mind my own business when reviewing posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, spam, spam-seeds

I was reviewing Triage and First Posts awhile ago, and came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965515/how-it-can-be-possible-to-integrate-alipay-payment-method-integration-in-codeign).

This looked a lot like spam seed to me (see this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363426/500276) on Meta), so I flagged it as such, which was declined (moderator could find no evidence to support it). Since the flag was declined, I'm assuming that the post in question didn't fit the profile that the mods are working off of.

I'm slowly but surely getting a handle on reviewing, so -- just to confirm -- is this another instance of "learning to love the skip button"?

I've caught a couple of these on audits, but they're pretty easy to spot (mainly because the post has already been deleted). But, if the post hasn't been deleted yet, for a post that *appears* to fit a known problem pattern (but it's a pattern that the mods are dealing with), I should just skip it and let the mods deal with it, right?

Comment: I might not have chosen the spam flag, but it for sure is too broad.

Comment: @BDL: Yeah, anytime I see a question with only 2 lines of text, my first thought is "too broad". But I read it a couple of times, and it seemed to serve no purpose other than hanging out a hook for a spam answer like the ones mentioned in the Meta post.

Comment: It's is not an advert for anything. Just because someone wants to use  a commercial service doesn't make it a spam post. That's a really bad question, and closing it as too broad is all that is needed. Yes, there have been some off-topic posts lately that also were being used as set-ups for spam answers, but just flagging to close such posts (as off topic) is fine.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield if someone would ask "I want to integrate paypal in codeigniter", would you judge the question as too broad or as spam?