# Audit links should point to the revision that was audited

Tags: bug, review-audits, bug-reporting-process

**TL;DR**. Audit links should point to the post revision that was audited, instead of the latest one. Pointing to the latest revision can incorrectly lead to the conclusion that either audit was bad, or that it was OP's fault to fail the audit (false positives or false negatives).

I discovered this when I stumbled upon this question: [How is this a bad answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361263/how-is-this-a-bad-answer).

In a few words, the audit link posted in the question is outdated, as it currently points to this revision:
[image]

However, when the OP failed audit, the answer was something along the lines of

[image]

Now, if we were to follow the audit link, we'd find a non-valid answer, which would indicate the OP correctly failed the audit, while the OP reviewed a completely different version of the answer.

Comment: Note that you have that in the /timeline. The timeline shows any review task and when it was failed.

Comment: While this is true, this doesn't help with the situation. It just confirms that we have the data to solve this bug. When viewing an audit link, we want to review the audit. Not reviewing some action which is different to the content. @Braiam