# Duplicate answer as review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

This question is about the review audit system specifically, not a question about how to deal with duplicate answers in general.

---

I was reviewing late answers when I was [presented with the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22867025) (audit) (except the score was 0 and there were no comments):
[image]

Now, as it turned out, this answer had been posted verbatim previously. How is one supposed to know that when reviewing?

I've found other meta posts about duplicate questions as audits, but not necessarily about duplicate answers.

Shouldn't such posts be excluded as audits as there's no way to know that it's a duplicate answer without extensively checking the question? And even then you might think it's an audit where the author has been changed to not give away that it is a review audit that you're supposed to vote up.

Comment: It’s one of the things you should be checking for when reviewing late answers.

Comment: Check this [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts). It can help you when reviewing in the future.

Comment: @yivi that guide also says: *"An audit will not show the accurate score, or any comments, and may change the displayed username and reputation"*. Based on that, I should have gone to the question to carefully compare the two answers. In this case, I agree that it could be spotted as the first sentence is kind of different, but what if that's not the case? Would it still show up as an audit? In that case you cannot tell because it might just be that the user names are swapped by the audit algorithm.

Comment: @yivi also, if there are a few pages of other answers, should one go and review all of those too to make sure it isn't a duplicate of one of them? Perhaps it plagiarises part of a few of the other answers, maybe from answers to different questions altogether. While I agree that it's nice to spot if that's the case, isn't that beyond the scope of the review queue in terms of time and effort?

Comment: @yivi Even if the "other answers" field shows 0? :)

Comment: see also: [How is this a bad answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361512/839601)

Comment: @gnat thanks. For now I've decided not to review on SO. I'll limit myself to the other sites (which coincidentally don't have audits). Over on those sites, I get the feeling my reviews actually improve the experience of new users and the overall quality of the site. Over here it seems more like homework (no offense intended). ;P

Comment: Of all the questions, how is this question a duplicate of that one? I'm new to meta, so is the duplicate policy on meta "this must have been asked before, so let's find anything that looks remotely similar and get over with it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I believe this might be a bug in the audit system. If the user tries to view an answer that has been already deleted, the system should just count that as a pass. Because only two things can happen from there: Either the user will notice that the answer is not there and realize what is happening, or the user does not realize what is happening exactly because the answer was a duplicate.

Besides, "other answers: 0" is wrong in every way.